# ActionScript 1.0 and XMLSocket [serverCertificateStatus ]

Tags: flash, sockets, actionscript

I'm quite new to flash, but had a demand of writing something that'll be supported by older players as well, and it must be using ActionScript 1.0/Flash player 5.0

I've noticed you can't use: 'serverCertificateStatus' so this wouldn't work:

```
var sock = new XMLSocket;
trace(sock.serverCertificateStatus);
```

or otherwise echo the data to some dynamic text field/ conditional statement and so forth.

Is there a way to verify a certificate via ActionScript 1.0?

If not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Hi @wvxvw , i've been following this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/security/CertificateStatus.html by adobe and it does exactly what i need - that is, verifying the **SSL certificate** on various levels. As far as i could tell, XMLSockets are available with FLP5 and they work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

i m wondering what kind of project you re working on, because nower days we have as3 ;)

you can use charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/) for debugging what data your flash player sends or receives. maybe this helps.

or switch to html5, because this ll be future. (if possible in your project)

Comment: i m so sorry to didn t spot out that limitaion combaining between html5 and as1..anyway, charles still should work